# How do I set the culture before the layout renders in symfony 1.4?

Tags: symfony1, internationalization, symfony-1.4

I need to display a different logo image (in layout.php) based on the country from which the site is being browsed. Setting it in the action doesn't work, as the layout is rendered before preExecute() (or any other action) is called.

How would I set the culture before the layout is rendered and then call on this variable in layout.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's true. Layout is rendered after action is called. The example is that you can change de layout in the actions.class with $this->setLayout();
Anyway, I think that you can use one slot to solve your problem. 
In layout:

```
<?php if(!has_slot('logo_image')) { ?>
<img src="<?php ... default logo;?>" />
<?php else { include_slot('logo_image'); } ?>
```

then, in your action template (f.e. indexSuccess)

```
<?php
slot('logo_image');
?><img src="<?php .... l10n image ?>" />
<?php end_slot(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should read the user culture [section](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/13-I18n-and-L10n#chapter_13_user_culture) of the docs. When you setup user culture properly, you can use `$sf_user->getCulture()` in templates and in the layout as well.

Note: @glerendegui is right the layout is rendered after the action and even after the template.